# Can't manage to make a static page with Zend Framework (about us)

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, static

I'm trying to make a website using the Zend Framework because I heard it was really good and I'd like to experiment with frameworks, but I have a simple problem driving me crazy.

I'd like to make a simple mywebsite.com/about page with static content because there is no need to do anything else than display html.

I made an About controller, the phtml associated with it, but when I try to go to /about, I get a 404 error followed by:

```
The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.

Controller:
not-found(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: not-found)
```

So I checked my routing file:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'about' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/about',
            ),
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'About\Controller\About',
                'action' => 'index',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

so if I'm not wrong this is supposed to call the About controller that I made, but can't manage to find the problem.

If someone could help me understand what I missed or what I didn't get with Zend, I will be very glad.

EDIT: The version of Zend is 2.x if that changes anything

#

EDIT 2: I found the solution thanks to the help of James Kent

My routing file seemed to be wrong, here is the new one :

```
    'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'about' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/about',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'About\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'About',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

I also had to change the indexAction of my About controller:

```
class AboutController extends AbstractActionController
{
public function nolayoutAction() {
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    //$viewModel->setTerminal(true); Uncomment to disable the layout
    return $viewModel;
}

public function indexAction()
{
    $viewModel = $this->nolayoutAction();
    return $viewModel;
}
}
```

I hope it will help some people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can recall, something like this should work:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
    'about',
    array('controller' => 'about')
);
$router->addRoute('about', $route);
```

In the meantime, I'm going to look for the documentation where I originally learned about this.

*Edit:* As it turns out, what you may need are Custom Routes, and their documentation is over [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but am I supposed to put that in the module.config.php of my About controller ?

Comment: I haven't used Zend for a fair while now, but I'm pretty sure that's where it goes.

Comment: @JayZus You might also want to check out this link: It's a tutorial on how to create a "Simple project" with Zend *but* it also shows you how to handle static pages, so it might be worth the read: http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/creating-a-simple-project-with-the-zend-framework-part1/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I searched for something like that for a while.
But in all tutorials like that they all have a zf executable that I don't have. They also have bootstrap.php and it doesn't exist in mine. 
Does it come from the fact that I have a 2.x version instead of 1.x ? 
Even the architecture of the directories is different ...

Comment: I'd assume that would be why things are so different. I just found another, though for version 1.1, which handles a static About page in Zend (http://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/routing-and-serving-up-static-content-with-zend-framework-1-10-4-2/) but I can't find any more information, other than the official documentation, about the 2.x version.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to find what the problem was with your previous links :-)
I'll make an edit of my post explaining how to do that.